# Matrix applications to image in GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, matrix, matlab-guide

I am trying to simply multiply a matrix to an image an get an output, and all of this has to be done in matlab GUIDE. I am not experienced in the language and due date is really soon, this is the code:

```
function t1_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

imgview=imread('1.jpg');
imshow(imgview)

guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = t1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = handles.output;

function slider3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
B=4;
set(handles.imgview,'CData',B);
```

I am trying simply to let the slider pick a number to multiply to the image for now, or let a value when clicking a button multiply the image!

image of gui:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/821/testojh.jpg/

Comment: You need to give more details for a usable answer. The code you post is meaningless without the corresponding figure.

Comment: Hey, I added an image of the GUI. All i need is the image to be affected when clicking the button. Multiplying a matrix or a number to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to remember is to pass the results back at the end of the pushbutton callback with guidata(hObject, handles). Also any modifications you make with additional written functions should return modified handles data.